# Android Studio - unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'getProguard()

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard

I am running an existing android project on Android Studio 0.6.1 on a Mac but am getting this error: 
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'getProguard()'!

I've tried upgrading to the latest Android Studio but that had the same issue, I've also tried all the solutions described in the following Issue forum: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419 as many others seemed to have a similar issue which they have resolved. Namely, updating to SDK tools rev 23.0.2, and downloading the latest adt bundle.

The proguard folder does actually appear in sdk > Tools as well so it's not actually a problem with proguard being missing.

Here is the root build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
```

And the build.gradle in the main module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-hockeyapp-plugin:1.1+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'hockeyApp'

configurations {
    apt
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'

    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar');
    tree.exclude 'android-support-v4.jar'
    compile tree;

    apt fileTree(dir: 'compile-libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile project(':thirdparty:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':thirdparty:DaoCore')
    compile project(':thirdparty:SlidingMenu-master:library')
    compile project(':thirdparty:jump.android:Jump')
    compile project(':thirdparty:drag-sort-listview')
    compile project(':thirdparty:AndroidHorizontalListView')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src','.apt_generated']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src','.apt_generated']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src','.apt_generated']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src-gen','src','.apt_generated']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }   

    signingConfigs {
        releaseSigning {

        storeFile file('***')          
        storePassword ***
        keyAlias ***
        keyPassword ***
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseSigning
        }
    }

    hockeyapp {
        apiToken = "***"
        releaseType = 0
        notify = 0
        status = 2
        notesType = 1

        notes = "This is an automatic upload"
        symbolsDirectory = file("build/symbols/")
        mappingFileNameRegex = "R.txt"
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    ext.aptOutput = file(".apt_generated")
    ext.aptOutput.deleteDir()
    ext.aptOutput.mkdirs()

    variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
        '-processorpath', configurations.apt.asPath,
        '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
        '-s', ext.aptOutput
    ]
}

// clean generated files
task clean(overwrite:true) {
    delete fileTree(dir: ".apt_generated")  
}
```

Another developer here has been able to get the project up and running fine on his Windows 8 Desktop with the same version of Android Studio & Gradle so I don't think it could be anything to do with the project itself however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because v1.1 of the HockeyApp plugin is incompatible with v0.11 of the Android Gradle plugin. According to the release notes for HockeyApp (https://github.com/x2on/gradle-hockeyapp-plugin/releases) you should be using 2.1.